# How to do real time Raytracing in unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raytracing

I am making a video-game in unity, and decided to use ray-tracing. I have the code, But as you will see in a second. It isn't exactly rendering frame by frame. 
Here is my raytracing code, this is the main script attached to the main camera.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RayTracer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Color backgroundColor = Color.black;
    public float RenderResolution = 1f;
    public float maxDist = 100f;
    public int maxRecursion = 4;


    private Light[] lights;
    private Texture2D renderTexture;

    void Awake()
    {
        renderTexture = new Texture2D((int)(Screen.width * RenderResolution), (int)(Screen.height * RenderResolution));
        lights = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Light)) as Light[];
    }

    void Start()
    {
        RayTrace();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), renderTexture);
    }

    void RayTrace()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < renderTexture.width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < renderTexture.height; y++)
            {
                Color color = Color.black;
                Ray ray = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x / RenderResolution, y / RenderResolution, 0));

                renderTexture.SetPixel(x, y, TraceRay(ray, color, 0));
            }
        }

        renderTexture.Apply();
    }

    Color TraceRay(Ray ray, Color color, int recursiveLevel)
    {

        if (recursiveLevel < maxRecursion)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDist))
            {
                Vector3 viewVector = ray.direction;
                Vector3 pos = hit.point + hit.normal * 0.0001f;
                Vector3 normal = hit.normal;

                RayTracerObject rto = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<RayTracerObject>(); 
                //Does the object we hit have that script?
                if (rto == null)
                {
                    var GO = hit.collider.gameObject;
                    Debug.Log("Raycast hit failure! On " + GO.name + " position " + GO.transform.position.ToString());
                    return color; //exit out
                }

                Material mat = hit.collider.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
                if (mat.mainTexture)
                {
                    color += (mat.mainTexture as Texture2D).GetPixelBilinear(hit.textureCoord.x, hit.textureCoord.y);
                }
                else
                {
                    color += mat.color;
                }

                color *= TraceLight(rto, viewVector, pos, normal);

                if (rto.reflectiveCoeff > 0)
                {
                    float reflet = 2.0f * Vector3.Dot(viewVector, normal);
                    Ray newRay = new Ray(pos, viewVector - reflet * normal);
                    color += rto.reflectiveCoeff * TraceRay(newRay, color, recursiveLevel + 1);
                }

                if (rto.transparentCoeff > 0)
                {
                    Ray newRay = new Ray(hit.point - hit.normal * 0.0001f, viewVector);
                    color += rto.transparentCoeff * TraceRay(newRay, color, recursiveLevel + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return color;

    }

    Color TraceLight(RayTracerObject rto, Vector3 viewVector, Vector3 pos, Vector3 normal)
    {
        Color c = RenderSettings.ambientLight;

        foreach (Light light in lights)
        {
            if (light.enabled)
            {
                c += LightTrace(rto, light, viewVector, pos, normal);
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    Color LightTrace(RayTracerObject rto, Light light, Vector3 viewVector, Vector3 pos, Vector3 normal)
    {


        float dot, distance, contribution;
        Vector3 direction;
        switch (light.type)
        {
            case LightType.Directional:
                contribution = 0;
                direction = -light.transform.forward;
                dot = Vector3.Dot(direction, normal);
                if (dot > 0)
                {
                    if (Physics.Raycast(pos, direction, maxDist))
                    {
                        return Color.black;
                    }

                    if (rto.lambertCoeff > 0)
                    {
                        contribution += dot * rto.lambertCoeff;
                    }
                    if (rto.reflectiveCoeff > 0)
                    {
                        if (rto.phongCoeff > 0)
                        {
                            float reflet = 2.0f * Vector3.Dot(viewVector, normal);
                            Vector3 phongDir = viewVector - reflet * normal;
                            float phongTerm = max(Vector3.Dot(phongDir, viewVector), 0.0f);
                            phongTerm = rto.reflectiveCoeff * Mathf.Pow(phongTerm, rto.phongPower) * rto.phongCoeff;

                            contribution += phongTerm;
                        }
                        if (rto.blinnPhongCoeff > 0)
                        {
                            Vector3 blinnDir = -light.transform.forward - viewVector;
                            float temp = Mathf.Sqrt(Vector3.Dot(blinnDir, blinnDir));
                            if (temp != 0.0f)
                            {
                                blinnDir = (1.0f / temp) * blinnDir;
                                float blinnTerm = max(Vector3.Dot(blinnDir, normal), 0.0f);
                                blinnTerm = rto.reflectiveCoeff * Mathf.Pow(blinnTerm, rto.blinnPhongPower) * rto.blinnPhongCoeff;

                                contribution += blinnTerm;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return light.color * light.intensity * contribution;
            case LightType.Point:
                contribution = 0;
                direction = (light.transform.position - pos).normalized;
                dot = Vector3.Dot(normal, direction);
                distance = Vector3.Distance(pos, light.transform.position);
                if ((distance < light.range) && (dot > 0))
                {
                    if (Physics.Raycast(pos, direction, distance))
                    {
                        return Color.black;
                    }

                    if (rto.lambertCoeff > 0)
                    {
                        contribution += dot * rto.lambertCoeff;
                    }
                    if (rto.reflectiveCoeff > 0)
                    {
                        if (rto.phongCoeff > 0)
                        {
                            float reflet = 2.0f * Vector3.Dot(viewVector, normal);
                            Vector3 phongDir = viewVector - reflet * normal;
                            float phongTerm = max(Vector3.Dot(phongDir, viewVector), 0.0f);
                            phongTerm = rto.reflectiveCoeff * Mathf.Pow(phongTerm, rto.phongPower) * rto.phongCoeff;

                            contribution += phongTerm;
                        }
                        if (rto.blinnPhongCoeff > 0)
                        {
                            Vector3 blinnDir = -light.transform.forward - viewVector;
                            float temp = Mathf.Sqrt(Vector3.Dot(blinnDir, blinnDir));
                            if (temp != 0.0f)
                            {
                                blinnDir = (1.0f / temp) * blinnDir;
                                float blinnTerm = max(Vector3.Dot(blinnDir, normal), 0.0f);
                                blinnTerm = rto.reflectiveCoeff * Mathf.Pow(blinnTerm, rto.blinnPhongPower) * rto.blinnPhongCoeff;

                                contribution += blinnTerm;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (contribution == 0)
                {
                    return Color.black;
                }
                return light.color * light.intensity * contribution;
            case LightType.Spot:
                contribution = 0;
                direction = (light.transform.position - pos).normalized;
                dot = Vector3.Dot(normal, direction);
                distance = Vector3.Distance(pos, light.transform.position);
                if (distance < light.range && dot > 0)
                {
                    float dot2 = Vector3.Dot(-light.transform.forward, direction);
                    if (dot2 > (1 - light.spotAngle / 180))
                    {
                        if (Physics.Raycast(pos, direction, distance))
                        {
                            return Color.black;
                        }
                        if (rto.lambertCoeff > 0)
                        {
                            contribution += dot * rto.lambertCoeff;
                        }
                        if (rto.reflectiveCoeff > 0)
                        {
                            if (rto.phongCoeff > 0)
                            {
                                float reflet = 2.0f * Vector3.Dot(viewVector, normal);
                                Vector3 phongDir = viewVector - reflet * normal;
                                float phongTerm = max(Vector3.Dot(phongDir, viewVector), 0.0f);
                                phongTerm = rto.reflectiveCoeff * Mathf.Pow(phongTerm, rto.phongPower) * rto.phongCoeff;

                                contribution += phongTerm;
                            }
                            if (rto.blinnPhongCoeff > 0)
                            {
                                Vector3 blinnDir = -light.transform.forward - viewVector;
                                float temp = Mathf.Sqrt(Vector3.Dot(blinnDir, blinnDir));
                                if (temp != 0.0f)
                                {
                                    blinnDir = (1.0f / temp) * blinnDir;
                                    float blinnTerm = max(Vector3.Dot(blinnDir, normal), 0.0f);
                                    blinnTerm = rto.reflectiveCoeff * Mathf.Pow(blinnTerm, rto.blinnPhongPower) * rto.blinnPhongCoeff;

                                    contribution += blinnTerm;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (contribution == 0)
                {
                    return Color.black;
                }
                return light.color * light.intensity * contribution;
        }
        return Color.black;
    }

    float max(float x0, float x1)
    {
        return x0 > x1 ? x0 : x1;
    }
}
```

And this is the code attached to the Objects in the scene

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RayTracerObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float lambertCoeff = 1f;

    public float reflectiveCoeff = 0f;

    public float phongCoeff = 1f;
    public float phongPower = 2f;

    public float blinnPhongCoeff = 1f;
    public float blinnPhongPower = 2f;

    public float transparentCoeff = 0f;


    public Color baseColor = Color.gray;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (!GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture)
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = baseColor;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this? And what would the code be?

Answer (score 6):

Though raytracing in the primary thread is a perfectly acceptable design, it's probably not what you want in Unity as it blocks everything else.

Now you could arguably spawn a child thread to perform the raytracing and having the primary thread render the results.  The problem though is that neither approach makes use of the GPU which sort of defeats the point using Unity in the first place.

> How to do real time Raytracing in unity with C#

It all depends on what your scene consists of and how you intend to render it. You could arguably render something simple in real-time at low resolution, however rendering with a reasonable screen resolution and with reasonable levels of ray bouncing i.e. the number of recursive light rays cast with reflective or transmissive materials would perhaps be much more difficult.

Instead I would urge you to follow the changing trend in raytracing where *realtime raytracing* is now being performed on the GPU using techniques known as ***General Purpose GPU*** or *GPGPU*.  nVidia has some talks on this subject and are available on YouTube.  [Here is my sample Unity GPGPU galaxy simulation](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/n-body-galaxy-simulation-using-compute-shaders-on-gpgpu-via-unity-3d/) that might prove useful as a background to GPGPU.

Sample GPGPU kernel merely to show you what GPGPU is about:

```
// File: Galaxy1Compute.compute

// Each #kernel tells which function to compile; you can have many kernels
#pragma kernel UpdateStars

#include "Galaxy.cginc"

// blackmagic
#define BLOCKSIZE   128

RWStructuredBuffer<Star> stars;

Texture2D HueTexture;

// refer to http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/163591-Compute-Shader-SamplerState-confusion
SamplerState samplerHueTexture;

// time ellapsed since last frame
float deltaTime;

const float Softening=3e4f;
#define Softening2  Softening * Softening

static float G = 6.67300e-11f;
static float DefaultMass = 1000000.0f;

// Do a pre-calculation assuming all the stars have the same mass
static float GMM = G*DefaultMass*DefaultMass;


[numthreads(BLOCKSIZE,1,1)]
void UpdateStars (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint i = id.x;
    uint numStars, stride;
    stars.GetDimensions(numStars, stride);

    float3 position = stars[i].position;
    float3 velocity = stars[i].velocity;

    float3 A=float3(0,0,0);

    [loop]
    for (uint j = 0; j < numStars; j++)
    {       
        if (i != j)
        {
            float3 D = stars[j].position - stars[i].position;
            float r   = length(D); 
            float f = GMM / (r * r + Softening2);
            A += f * normalize(D);
        }
    }

    velocity += A * deltaTime;
    position += velocity * deltaTime;

    if (i < numStars)
    {
        stars[i].velocity = velocity;
        stars[i].position = position;
        stars[i].accelMagnitude = length(A);
    }

    
}
```

Additionally there are some fine books on the subject.   *[Real-time Volume Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568812663)*, though it covers volumes, it does cover casting rays - the essence of ray-tracing.  The hardest paradigm shift is the writing for GPGPU, once you understand it, writing a GPGPU raytracer is an easy step from GPGPU volume shaders.

[image]

A marvellous tome to accompany any raytrace author is Matt Pharr's [Physically Based Rendering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012553180X) book (there is a 2nd edition but I have not read that)

[image]

### More

- *[GPU Ray Tracing in Unity – Part 1](http://blog.three-eyed-games.com/2018/05/03/gpu-ray-tracing-in-unity-part-1/)*

Comment: So if I write a computer shade in Unity3D that does ray tracing, and have either a RTX series GPU or a nvidia "real time ray tracing capable" card such as a 1080, does it automatically make it "real time" or is something else needed to use the capability of the RTX?

Comment: @RaenirSalazar I've seen the marketing for those too and am not sure why they claim people need to buy a new card. So long as your card can do **compute shaders** you should be fine. e.g. GTX 980 can do real-time ray tracing based on code I found [here](http://blog.three-eyed-games.com/2018/05/03/gpu-ray-tracing-in-unity-part-1/).  I'm using it in my own projects :)  Try the code with your own code before purchasing.  There is no magic "ray tracing" instruction, just pure _GPGPU kernels_

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia announced [NVIDIA RTX™](https://developer.nvidia.com/rtx), a ray-tracing technology that brings real-time, cinematic-quality rendering to content creators and game developers.

It consists of a ray-tracing engine running on [NVIDIA Volta](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/volta-gpu-architecture/) architecture GPUs. It’s designed to support ray tracing through a variety of interfaces.

And these results in bringing the game developers to do raycasting in their work to get a movie quality output.

https://nvidianews.nvidia.com/news/nvidia-rtx-technology-realizes-dream-of-real-time-cinematic-rendering

Unity in the future update would support this new DirectX Raytracing API. Then the game developers can enjoy the photorealistic quality output in their unity rendering pipeline.

Comment: RTX is [not required](http://blog.three-eyed-games.com/2018/05/03/gpu-ray-tracing-in-unity-part-1/) to perform real-time ray-tracing via GPGPU

Answer (score -2):

So after we all saw a hype around RTX cards, we need to answer a question, what is it actually doing? Well, basically it is hardware accelerated raycaster, which is well optimized to do its job at it.

But nobody said you can't do hardware accelerated raycasting on let's say any other graphics card. In Unity, you have access to hardware acceleration in the form of shaders. you can write your own raycaster with the power of compute shaders. which will be much slower then very very optimized RTX cards but give you an advantage in some areas.

But hey man, since it is slower then RTX why would I need to do so. Well, in general, you can enhance your rendring with this method. For example softening shadows, attempting Global illumination, all sorts of stuff. But to answer your question, you won't be able to do a full-blown raytracing without RTX cards.